# What makes an interval compact or non-compact?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

This question has been asked here several times but I still have some gaps in my knowledge. 
So $(0,1)$ is non-compact while $[0,1]$ is. The explanations usually involve creating a set $(\frac{1}{n},1)$. Here is what I do not understand.

Why can't we just construct a set like $\{(-1,2)\}$? It is an open set. It is a finite collection. 
I know Heine-Borel theorem and that it implies that a closed and bounded set is compact. So somehow, I figure $[0,1]$ is compact because it a $1$-cell.

The book I am using (baby Rudin, I understand, it is called) has not discussed any sequences as such. So what am I doing wrong by choosing a set like $(-2,2)$ or some such.

Comment: Every open cover of a given set must admit a finite subcover for that given set to be compact. Producing one that works is not enough. Producing one that does not work shows the set cannot be compact. Its all in the quantifiers.

Comment: the key is in the quantifiers "for all" and "there exist". The definition of compactness is that: A subset $K \subset X$ (say $X$ is a metric space because that's how I recall Rudin does things) is called compact if FOR EVERY open cover $\{G_{\alpha}\}$ of $K$, THERE EXISTS a finite subcover $\{G_{\alpha_i}\}_{i=1}^l$. You've listed a few true statements, but they do not satisfy this definition (since you completely ignored everything about the quantifiers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compactness means: **every** open cover has a finite subcover. It does not suffice to check that there is one finite subcover! You have to check them all.

---

$(-1,2)$ has an open cover without finite subcover:

$$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (-1+1/n, 2-1/n) = (-1,2)$$

Thus $(-1,2)$ is not compact.

Alternatively,$(-1,2)$ is not closed (thus it can't be compact).

---

The interval $[0,1]$ is compact because it is closed and bounded (Heine-Borel).

Comment: Thanks. So if I understand correctly, it is rather difficult to collectively analyze **every** open cover. Hence, we usually try to produce a counter-example that disproves compactness. That, I guess, is the purpose of creating various sets. Is that correct?

Comment: Analyzing every open cover is in practice impossible (sometimes it can!, try to prove for example that $\{1/n: n \geq 1\} \cup \{0\}$ is compact with the open cover definition). For disproving compactness, it suffices to find one cover without finite subcover. But proving compactness is usually done using other tools than the definition (for example Heine Borel if your set lives in an Euclidean space). The open cover definition is this way because it is the definition that extends to the most general context (metric spaces, then topology).

Answer (score 7):

If I said "All odd numbers are prime" and to prove it I produced the number $5$, you wouldn't accept that.

If I said "All open covers contain a finite subcover"  and produce only the open cover $(-1,2)$, why would you accept that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $(0,1)\subset(-1,2)$, and yes, $(-1,2)$ is open and, yes, $\bigl\{(-1,2)\bigr\}$ is finite. However, asserting that $(0,1)$ is compact means that for *every* set oven open subsets of $\mathbb R$ whose union contains $(0,1)$, there is a finite subse whose union still contains $(0,1)$.

And now consider $\Lambda=\left\{\left(\frac1n,1-\frac1n\right)\,\middle|\,n\in\{3,4,5,\ldots\}\right\}$ has the property that the union of its elements conains $(0,1)$. However, this doesn't happen for *any* finite subset of $\Lambda$.

Answer (score 1):

A subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded $\textbf{or}$ if and only if every sequence in that set has a subsequence that converges to a limit point contained in the set $\textbf{or}$ if and only if every cover of the set consisting only of open sets has a finite subcover (i.e. you can somehow choose finitely many of those open sets such that they still cover the whole set). $(-2,2)$ isn't compact because it is not closed. Alternatively, you can pick a sequence that converges to $-2$ or $2$, e.g. $x_n = 2-\frac{1}{n}$. Then, $(x_n) \in (-2,2)^\mathbb{N}$ but $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_n \not\in (-2,2)$. Alternatively, you can find an open cover of $(-2,2)$ that does not have a finite subcover (what about $A_n = (-2+\frac{1}{n},2-\frac{1}{n})$?).